# Rank one adjoint operators on a Lie algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a (finite dimensional) semi-simple Lie algebra over a field $k$ and let $x \in \mathfrak{g}$. By definition, we have the equivalence:
$$ \mathrm{rk}(\mathrm{ad}_x) = 0 \iff x = 0,$$
where $\mathrm{rk}(\mathrm{ad}_x)$ is the rank of $\mathrm{ad}_x$ seen as an element of $\mathrm{End}(\mathfrak{g})$. I would like to know if there is a classification of elements $x \in \mathfrak{g}$ such that $\mathrm{rk}(\mathrm{ad}_x) \leq 1$? I am primarily interested in the case where $k = \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathfrak{g}$ is simple of classical type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another approach.

To show it's impossible (the rank can't be 1), it is enough to show this when the field (assumed of char 0) is algebraically closed, and in turn it's enough to show the result in case $\mathfrak{g}$ is simple. If $x$ has $\mathrm{ad}(x)$ of rank 1, $x$ has centralizer of codimension 1. It is known (see e.g. [this MathSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3004226/35400)) that $\mathfrak{g}$ has no subalgebra of codimension 1, unless $\mathfrak{g}$ is 3-dimensional. But for $\mathfrak{sl}_2$, the operator $\mathrm{ad}_x$ has rank 2 for every nonzero $x$ (alternatively, all 2-dimensional subalgebras have a trivial centralizer, so can't be centralizer of an element).

A similar approach can be used (with a little further work) to classify which $\mathfrak{g}$ admit an $x$ with $\mathrm{ad}(x)$ of rank 2, and classify such elements $x$.

Comment: Do you know the answer for the classification of the existence of a rank-$2$ adjoint operator? \\ Also, why does the field need to be of characteristic $0$?  Do you use it only for the non-existence of subalgebras of codimension $1$?

Comment: @LSpice As regards positive char.: I'm not sure: this might depend on the definition of "semisimple" (I'm not sure what it is in positive char.).

Comment: Ah, [good point](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412736/rank-one-adjoint-operators-on-a-lie-algebra/412759#comment1057841_412759).  I took it to mean "Lie algebra of a semi-simple algebraic group over $k$".

Comment: @LSpice As regards rank 2 adjoint operator: I haven't checked details (I'd need to check the list of simple Lie algebras with a codimension 2 subalgebra) etc, to formulate the right conclusion.

Comment: @LSpice can't the Lie algebra of a (nontrivial) semisimple $k$-group be abelian in some cases? I'm not familiar enough with this anyway to attempt any conclusion. The Killing form argument is nice anyway (of course one has to assume non-degenerate Killing form).

Comment: The Lie algebra of a non-trivial semisimple algebraic group can be soluble (e.g., $\operatorname{SL}_2$ in characteristic $2$), but not Abelian, since if it were so then it would remain so over the algebraic closure, and over the algebraic closure one has opposite root vectors whose commutator is a non-$0$ element of the CSA.  But certainly I agree with you that there is a lot of subtlety in positive characteristic.

Comment: @LSpice in any case if it's solvable (and nontrivial) then there's a codimension 1 ideal.

Comment: @YCor : Many thanks for this opening-perspetive answer.

Answer (score 8):

$\DeclareMathOperator\ad{ad}\DeclareMathOperator\rk{rk}$I claim that it is impossible to have $\rk(\ad_x) = 1$.

I'll assume that $\mathfrak g$ is $k$-split, which seems to be OK since you are interested in the case $k = \mathbb C$.  (Or you could just tensor up to $\overline k$, which does not change the rank of the adjoint operator.)  Let $\mathfrak h$ be a split Cartan subalgebra.

Suppose that $x \in \mathfrak g$ satisfies $\rk(\ad_x) = 1$.

If $x$ lies in $\mathfrak h$, $\beta$ is any root that does not vanish at $x$, and $E_\beta$ and $E_{-\beta}$ are non-$0$ vectors in the appropriate root spaces, then $\ad_x(E_\beta) = \beta(x)E_\beta$ and $\ad_x(E_{-\beta}) = -\beta(x)E_{-\beta}$ are non-$0$ elements of different root spaces, hence are linearly independent, which is a contradiction.

Thus, $x$ does not lie in $\mathfrak h$.  Let $x = \sum x_\alpha$ be the root-space decomposition with respect to $\mathfrak h$, where $\alpha$ runs over the roots of $\mathfrak h$ in $\mathfrak g$ and $0$, and choose a root $\alpha$ such that $x_\alpha$ is non-$0$.

We have that $\ad_x(h)$ equals $-\sum \alpha(h)x_\alpha$ for all $h \in \mathfrak h$.  Since all these elements lie on a common line, if $\beta \ne \pm\alpha$ is a root, then, since $\{\alpha, \beta\}$ and $\{\alpha, -\beta\}$ are linearly independent subsets of $\mathfrak h^*$, we have $x_\beta = 0$ and $x_{-\beta} = 0$.

Let $h$ be an element of $\mathfrak h$ not annihilated by $\alpha$.

We have that $\ad_x(h) = -\alpha(h)x_\alpha + \alpha(h)x_{-\alpha}$ and $\ad_x(x_\alpha)$ equals $\alpha(x_0)x_\alpha + \ad_{x_{-\alpha}}(x_\alpha)$.  Noting that $\ad_{x_{-\alpha}}(x_\alpha)$ lies in $\mathfrak h$ and comparing root-space decompositions of these linearly dependent elements shows that $\alpha(h)x_{-\alpha}$ equals $0$, so that $x_{-\alpha}$ equals $0$.  That is, $\ad_x(h)$ equals $-\alpha(h)x_\alpha$, hence is a non-$0$ element of the $\alpha$-root space.

If $x_0$ is non-$0$, then we can choose a root $\beta \ne -\alpha$ (possibly $\beta = \alpha$) such that $\beta(x_0) \ne 0$.  If $E_\beta$ is a non-$0$ element of the $\beta$-root space, then $\ad_x(E_\beta) = \beta(x_0)E_\beta + \ad_{x_\alpha}(E_\beta)$ has projection $\beta(x_0)E_\beta \ne 0$ on $\mathfrak h$, hence is linearly independent of $\ad_x(h)$, which is a contradiction.

Thus $x$ lies in the $\alpha$-root space.  If $E_{-\alpha}$ is a non-$0$ element of the $(-\alpha)$ root space, then $\ad_x(E_{-\alpha})$ is a non-$0$ element of $\mathfrak h$, hence is again linearly independent of $\ad_x(h)$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Alternatively, $ad_x$ preserves the Killing form, which is symmetric, bilinear and non-degenerate, and so the rank of $ad_x$ is even.

Comment: @HenrikWinther, [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412736/rank-one-adjoint-operators-on-a-lie-algebra/412752#comment1057808_412752) is a nicer argument, to the extent that I think it merits a separate answer.  (I wouldn't want to try to adapt my argument to show that the rank of the adjoint operator can't be $3$!)

Comment: @HenrikWinther, discussion with @‍YCor in the comments to their [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/412759), specifically [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412736/rank-one-adjoint-operators-on-a-lie-algebra/412759#comment1057845_412759), made me worry about positive characteristic: the Killing-form [approach](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412736/rank-one-adjoint-operators-on-a-lie-algebra/412759#comment1057808_412752) can fail in small positive characteristic, right?